# How can I use a generic type parameter for different structs that have a variable with the same type and name?

Tags: c#, struct

I have a method, `ListToString`, that takes a list and outputs the `name` element of all structs in the list. Each struct that I use `ListToString` for has a name element, but because I can't apply `name` to a generic type, I need to create an overload of `ListToString` for each struct. This has cost me about a hundred lines.

Example of what I want to happen:

```
public static string ListToString<T>(List<T> list, bool formatted)
{
    //Throws many errors because 'T' does not have a 'name' element
    string returnString = "";
    if (formatted)
    {
        if(list.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += list[0].name;
        }
        else if(list.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString = list[0].name + " and a " + list[1].name;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                returnString += list[i].name + ", ";
            }
            returnString += "and a " + list[list.Count - 1].name;
        }
    }
```

What happens instead:

```
public static string ListToString(List<World.Entities.Resource> list, bool formatted)
{
    string returnString = "";
    if (formatted)
    {
        if(list.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += list[0].name;
        }
        else if(list.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString = list[0].name + " and a " + list[1].name;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                returnString += list[i].name + ", ";
            }
            returnString += "and a " + list[list.Count - 1].name;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (World.Entities.Resource resource in list)
        {
            returnString += resource.name + ", ";
        }
    }
    return CapitalizeString(returnString);
}
public static string ListToString(List<World.Entities.Creature> list, bool formatted)
{
    string returnString = "";
    if (formatted)
    {
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += list[0].name;
        }
        else if (list.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString = list[0].name + " and a " + list[1].name;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                returnString += list[i].name + ", ";
            }
            returnString += "and a " + list[list.Count - 1].name;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (World.Entities.Creature creature in list)
        {
            returnString += creature.name + ", ";
        }
    }
    return CapitalizeString(returnString);
}
public static string ListToString(List<World.Entities.Structure> list, bool formatted)
{
    string returnString = "";
    if (formatted)
    {
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += list[0].name;
        }
        else if (list.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString = list[0].name + " and a " + list[1].name;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                returnString += list[i].name + ", ";
            }
            returnString += "and a " + list[list.Count - 1].name;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (World.Entities.Structure structure in list)
        {
            returnString += structure.name + ", ";
        }
    }
    return CapitalizeString(returnString);
}
public static string ListToString(List<World.Tools.Tool> list, bool formatted)
{
    string returnString = "";
    if (formatted)
    {
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            returnString += list[0].name;
        }
        else if (list.Count == 2)
        {
            returnString = list[0].name + " and a " + list[1].name;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                returnString += list[i].name + ", ";
            }
            returnString += "and a " + list[list.Count - 1].name;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (World.Tools.Tool tool in list)
        {
            returnString += tool.name + ", ";
        }
    }
    return CapitalizeString(returnString);
}
```

Each struct has a similar `name` element, so how can I incorporate a generic parameter to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're coming form a language which uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), i.e. if an object has a property called `name`, then any code knowing this fact can access this property without knowing the concrete type of the class.

Things don't quite work the same way in c# (`dynamic` aside). The idiomatic ways of implementing this pattern are either to derive all the relevant structs from a similar base type, or probably more suitable for your case, to have all structs implement an interface, e.g. `IName`, which has a property `Name`, and then add a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to your method, such as:

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public struct Creature : IName
{
    ...
}

public static string ListToString<T>(List<T> list, bool formatted) where T : IName
{
    ... //The compiler now knows that T is guaranteed to implement IName.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't know about interfaces or how they worked; I thought it had something to do with deriving from a base class like your example, but I wasn't sure.
C# is my main language, but I'm still not very well-versed in it...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a generic constraint:

```
public interface IThingWithAName
{
  string name { get;}
}
```

Make sure your classes implement IThingWithAName and

```
public static string ListToString<T>(List<T> list, bool formatted)
  where T : IThingWithAName
{
  // Now you can use list[0].name
}
```

also since you're not modifying the list, you can use:

```
public static string ListToString<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list, bool formatted)
  where T : IThingWithAName
```